# Codeigniter Youtube videos is not coming

Tags: codeigniter

I try to show a youtube video in my cms project using codeigniter. But its not working.. I insert the youtube url in one table path in my mysql database and i just call that url using codeigniter view area under iframe tag.. But its not showing i check it in the Browser inspect the video url is showing but below of the  tag  this is generated automatically. Can any one help me..

This is my view code..

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <?php foreach($advertisement as $ad) { ?>
          <table>
    <td>
  <iframe src="<?php echo $ad->url?>"
   width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
   </td>
   </table>

            <?php 
            } ?>
     </div>  
</div>
```

This is my Controller Code

```
  public function advertisement(){
        $data['advertisement'] = $this->modelHome->populateAds();

        $this->load->view('layouts/head',$data);    
        $this->load->view('commercial',$data);  
        $this->load->view('layouts/footer');    
    }
```

This is my modal code

```
 public function populateAds(){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('advertisement');
        $this->db->where('status','approved');
        $this->db->order_by('id','DESC');
        $query=$this->db->get();
         if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result();
        }
     }
```

This is my Table

[image]

Comment: Can you add the HTML code that is being output by this? View Source.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks ok.
Problem is with your data in database. If you look at the only record you have in your table, it has status **approve** not **approved**. And your model is selecting **only** rows with status **approved**.

Answer (score 0):

in your model

```
public function populateAds(){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('advertisement');
        $this->db->where('status','approve');
        $this->db->order_by('id','DESC');
        $query=$this->db->get();
         if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result();
        }
     }
```

Comment: I Try that but its not working... In my view area the you tube url is coming but the video only not showing

Comment: please use iframe for display videos